# How to force to use light theme in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7 app, I want to use the light theme, no matter what theme the user sets in the phone. How to do that ?

Do I need to custom the style or theme ? I just want the default light theme.

Thanks

Comment: If you do this to my phone, I will hunt you down and skin you alive. The light theme is very battery unfriendly.

Comment: Forcing a theme can be usefull for a panorama page. We often choose a dark background image and white text.

Answer (score 12):

Jeff Wilcox offers a good way to do this using a theme manager he developed.

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/

Comment: Not run on WP7.1, its for WP8, how to implement it VS2010 WP7.1

Comment: did you try with this version ?http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager/1.5.0

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice way of replacing the default brushes. Saves you setting Forecolor everywhere.

http://www.designersilverlight.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/

You'll still need to set the background of the main layout node to the default background brush.

```
Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to force an app to use a specific theme.

The best you can do is create your own style for every control you use and mimic the light theme in your styles.

Beware, this can be a time consuming and tedious task. Be sure to test all pages and all controls in all states when both the light and dark themes have been specified by the user.

I've had to do this (but for the dark theme) and it's not something I'd do again out of choice.

There are a few tips on doing this from one of the PDC sessions on optimising performance http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/10/28/pdc-live-optimizing-performance-for-silverlight-windows-phone-7-applications.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* bad idea.

Windows Phones use OLED displays - the pixels generate light directly, they are not backlit. Power consumption is therefore highest for white pixels. This is why Microsoft is suddenly obsessed with light text on dark backgrounds. It's not a back-to-the-seventies thing.

If you do this you will cause ridiculous power consumption.

For the benefit of the jerk who voted down a factually correct answer, I quote page 63 of the *Windows Phone 7 UI Design and Interaction Guide* published in July 2010 by Microsoft.

> **Avoid using too much white  in
>   applications, such as white 
>   backgrounds, as this may have an 
>   impact on battery life for devices
>   that  have organic LED displays.**

If you're wondering why Microsoft included a "light background" theme option, so am I.

Comment: Not all Windows Phone 7 phones use OLED displays. My HTC HD7 is a TFT LCD. The built-in Mail, Office apps, as well as the Facebook app uses white backgrounds.

Comment: Most of them do. But yours doesn't, and that's what's important, so bugger everyone else. The Office team is also famous for thinking the animated paperclip was a good idea.