# Is designing a white (light) skin for a dark WP 8 theme bad practice?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Im looking at designing an Windows Phone app and have been reading about the dark/light theming options.

The company brands Im designing to are based upon a majority white interface. As far as I can tell the devices default to dark.

Ive noticed that most apps dont account for this ability to switch, but would like peoples opinion/best practice or is there a technical option Ive missed.

So I design my white themed app against the WP 8 dark scheme or should I design against the light one only, and somehow force the user to use that?

Comment: "most apps dont account for this ability to switch" -> an app needs to be restarted after changing the theme.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your application theme agnostic. Simply override all styles in your global resource dictionary and your application will look the same regardless of the theme.

You can notice that default mail application in Windows Phone is always white. Also, Foursqare and Facebook applications are theme ignorant.

It is up to you if you wish to use personal styles for your app.

Comment: Actually in WP8 the mail app has a dark mode.

Comment: @rikkit I didn't know that, thanks for the info :) I am still stuck on WP7 :P

Comment: I was reading a bit more, and saw that some people have had rejections for this reason - not sure how true this is or not

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use a custom theme as long as it's done properly - it's mentioned in the [official docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202878(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of links after using different search terms

[How to force to use light theme in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096388/how-to-force-to-use-light-theme-in-windows-phone-7)
http://matthiasshapiro.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/

Seems this is the best solution

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/