# windows phone 8 theme override of default theme not working

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, themes

Hi im Currently developing a App for a Customer and the Customer wants a specific theme that matches there company colors.

and i am now trying to override the default themes so the customers theme will always be the ones used. I have currently tried the way from this this site :

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-mango-custom-application-theme-step-by-step

and also some suggestions from these :

[How to force to use light theme in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096388/how-to-force-to-use-light-theme-in-windows-phone-7)
http://matthiasshapiro.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/

these are some old post indeed but most should be the same in Windows phone 8

i cant get any of these to work even with moving the ThemeResource,xaml to the project and link it like wise :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ThemeResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

it stil uses the phones default theme Dark.

how ever i found out that if you dont use the default variables names like : PhoneBackgroundBrush

and use you own naming conventions then this works. I would prefer to just override the default variable names.

my problem is very like this on this post : [Custom Theme That Overrides Default Theme WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658951/custom-theme-that-overrides-default-theme-wp7)

Is there Really no way to override the default theme and its Variables or am i forced to make my own and go through all my controls to use my own naming convention ?

any help is very much appreciated.

regards 
Jens Simonsen

Answer (score 1):

In the default Resource Dictionary(s) at the bottom you'll see statements like;

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment them out or whatever and use the same thing at the bottom of your own Resource Dictionary instead with like;

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCustomButtonStyle}"/>
```

After that anything of that Type should inherit your Style Templates instead of the default ones and effectively apply your theme globally without having to implicitly define them all over the place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi chris thanks for replying i tried you suggestion out but i could not get it to work. til the same when it gets on the devices.

Comment: hi chris thanks for replying back i got it to work it appears that the file needs the build action to be set to resource after things started to run . tho i took things bit further went a got the phoneThememanager from nuget and that helped alot as well. so this is resolved now. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Yes sir, there's usually more to an issue than what's seen at first glance and I had a suspicion either that or how you were sharing them as merged was your culprit. Glad you found your remedy. If my answer was used be sure to mark it as such for others future reference. Cheers