# Overriding styling in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a dll that our customers integrate that provides UserControls and I want to allow style overrides.  In Windows Store I can do:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///MyDLL/Assets/Styles/Default.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///OverrideStyles.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and it finds the local AppboyStyles.xaml defined in the users app.  I can't figure out the right URI for Windows Phone 8 to allow similar functionality.

edit:

Say I have UserControl1 in A.dll, and UserControl1 has a style resource dictionary that looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/A;component/Assets/Styles/Default.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/TestApp;component/Assets/Styles/Override.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This will actually work in TestApp, but I can't hardcode one calling app because it's a library to be distributed.  So I need a way to either substitute for the calling app dll name, or use a URI that evaluates to the current app's resources.

Comment: Same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150583/windows-phone-8-theme-override-of-default-theme-not-working

Comment: No I'm not doing anything with themes, just need to allow static-resource overrides via merged resource dictionaries.

Comment: Have you tried merging the dictionaries in code/C# as opposed to XAML?

Comment: Yup - but that had a bunch of issues as well (mostly that I need static resources to be overridden, but the spot you can merge dictionaries happens after the Control's style is resolved.)